# Android; Using SimpleAdapter with setOnItemClick a Listview containing Checkboxes

Tags: listview, checkbox, onitemclicklistener, simpleadapter

I have a ListView in an Activity (Not ListActivity) that is populated by a SimpleAdapter.

```
public void updateGroupsInfoPane(){
    final ListView m_listview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.memberOfList);
    mapMemberOfList.clear();
    for (String group : arrayAccountMemberOfList) {
        Map<String, Object> datum = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        String[] tempString = group.split(",");
        datum.put("groupname", tempString[0]);
        datum.put("groupdesc", tempString[1]);
        mapMemberOfList.add(datum);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mapMemberOfList, R.layout.membersof_list, new String[] {"groupname", "groupdesc"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    m_listview3.setAdapter(adapter);

    m_listview3.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    m_listview3.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    m_listview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CheckBox box = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            String tempString = text1.getText().toString();

            if (box.isChecked()){
                box.setChecked(false);
                listCurrentMembership.remove(tempString);
            }else{
                box.setChecked(true);
                listCurrentMembership.add(tempString);
            };
        }
    });
}
```

This works fine. The problem is when I scroll this list, the checkboxes once off the screen to not re-check the correct ones, and then items on the next scroll are checked. The data is correct as I load it into a different array. Just the checkbox graphic is wrong. If I do not scroll, checking and un-checking adds and removes the correct data.

Searching around this is because of the recycling ListView, and I need to implement a getView.

I've been looking around for a while now at quite a few examples on how to to this with SimpleAdapter as some posts are saying SimpleAdapter already does getView, and other examples with ListActivity. Then how I am checking the boxes is just by tapping the ListView item, not the checkbox itself might have something to do with it? But I cannot find an example that sort of resembles what I am doing so that I can play around and fix this.

My XML for the items in the ListView 'membersof_list' is:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/vw1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:checked="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="6sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just have an array of data, I empty the array that is associated with the ListView because I do need to clear it before loading new/different data, I split the data at the comma to load it into groupname and groupdesc. The checkboxes are all unchecked by default and that's how it should be.

I am new to Android programming, and I know it's not the cleanest or most efficient code, but once it's working I plan to revisit this and make it better.

Any suggestions, links, examples would be valuable. Thanks.